# Can you trigger a signal upon partial update of django object via the django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I started noticing that the `patch` method in django rest framework doesn't actually trigger signals, `post` methods seem to work fine. This is what I have:

```
@receiver(signals.pre_save, sender=Example)
def populate_time_fields_based_on_state(sender, **kwargs):
    example = kwargs.get('instance')
    if example.start_datetime is None and example.projected_end_datetime is None and example.state.label == 'Assigned':
        example.start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
        example.projected_end_datetime = example.created_datetime + datetime.timedelta(
            days=example.som_field)
        example.save()
```

And I'm testing this via:

```
client = APIClient()
client.patch(f'/api/example/1/', {'state': 'Assigned'})
```

Is there a way to tell it to trigger the signal? Do I need to override the update method in my serializer? I'm trying this:

```
def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
    instance = self.get_object()
    instance.save()
    return response
```

But it's quite hacky

Comment: Is the receiver activated(usually by importing in app.ready)? can you confirm it is called by saving an object in django console?

Comment: Seconding @Ken4scholars.  I have many pre & post save hooks and have no issue with them firing, and they are integral to the app.  In my `app-name/apps.py` in the `ready` method I have something like `import app_name.signals` where `signals.py` has them defined.  I have an old import of signals in a model file and that works fine.  As a last resort, add a `print('here')` to the signals file, and when running manage.py it should print out if its importedl

Comment: Also, you don't need to override.  The base serializer's update() method calls instance.save() as normal, so what you have is effectively the same.

Comment: Ah @AndrewBacker I think that was my issue, the signals weren't being imported into the main app. Where would you generally import all the signals? I could import them into the models file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app directory there should be an `apps.py`, [see the docs for the format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#methods) of it.

Generally it ends up looking like the following, as opposed to the example where they wire up the signal manually.  Note that I have a "project/apps/" structure here, but just change the module name depending on where the files actually live:

```
#project/apps/my_app/__init__.py
default_app_config = 'project.apps.my_app.apps.MyAppConfig'

#project/apps/my_app/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "project.apps.my_app"
    verbose_name = "MyApp"

    def ready(self):
        from project.apps.my_app import signals
        # ... other init &/or logging
```

Note: *Feel free to delete the line in **init**.py, and play with the `name` in the app config.  I'm not sure how critical they actually are*